# can anyone tell where i am doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a simple todo list with HTML, CSS, and jQuery and I am facing a problem, it's not adding new to-dos input as I want them, here's the code, it will be great if anyone can point out where I am doing wrong.

//HTML 
Here's the HTML tag,it look fine for me

```
<head>
<title>TODO list</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assests/css/todos.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/lib/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>TO-DO List<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Todo">
        <ul>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Go To Potions Class</li>
            <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Buy New Robes</li>
        <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> Visit Hogrid</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/todos.js"></script>
</body>
```

//css

```
h1{
   background: #2980b9;
   color: white;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: normal;
}
ul{
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#container{
   box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
   width: 360px;
   margin: 100px auto;
   background: #f7f7f7;
}

.completed{
   color: gray;
   text-decoration: line-through;
}
body{
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   background: #2BC0E4;  /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4);  /*     Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
   background: linear-gradient(to right, #EAECC6, #2BC0E4); /* W3C, IE 10+/     Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}
li{
   background: white;
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   color: #666;
}
li:nth-child(2n){
   background: #f7f7f7;
}

input{
   font-size: 18px;
   background:#f7f7f7;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 13px 13px 20px 20px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   color: #2980b9;
   border:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
input:focus{
   background:white;
   border: 3px solid #2980b9;
   outline: none;
}

.fa-plus{
   float: right;
}
span{
   background-color: #e74c3c;
   height:40px;
   margin-right: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   width:0px;
   display:inline-block;
   transition: 0.2s linear;
   opacity:0;
}
li:hover span{
   width:40px;
   opacity:1.0;
}
```

//jQuery

And here's the jquery tag,I am following the "Web Developer Bootcamp" course and I have to make a TO-DO List by using these code and I write exact same code,but it's still not working,when I want to add new TO-Dos it's adding but not showing up,it creates a blank li and when I hover over the li it's showing up in a typical manner.
    //check of specific TODOs by clicking

```
$("ul").on("click","li",function(){
   $(this).toggleClass("completed");
});
//click on X to delete TODO 


$("ul").on("click","span",function(event){
   //to remove parent lis
   $(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
event.stopPropagation();
});

//adding new TODO

$("input[type='text'").keypress(function(event){
   if(event.which===13){
       //grabbing new TODO text from input
    var todoText= $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");
    //create a new li and add to ul
    $("ul").append("<li><span><i class='fa fa-trash'><span> " + todoText    +"</li>")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector for the input is missing the right brackets:

```
$("input[type='text'")
```

Comment: This is only one of the issues. The desired behavior will be achieved by closing the span tag where the OP is appending the new li element. See provided jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rg2n8rd8/

Comment: thanks a lot ,i clearly missed that,thanks again